# Android Tests skipped due to test package parsing error in AWS Device Farm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Just started with Espresso test case in android and AWS DF from  this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O11nhUm8MKo). When uploading both APK's(build, AndroidTest) in AWS device Farm, it says  -"Tests skipped due to test package parsing error. Please check Parsing result for more details."

Parsing result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Setup Suite", 
        "tests": [
            {
                "name": "Setup Test"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Teardown Suite", 
        "tests": [
            {
                "name": "Teardown Test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the chance can you let me know the result of these questions:

- To rule out an issue with the device can we run the same apk with a fuzz test?
- If the app is successful, do the sample tests also work?

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android

- If these tests work then can you paste a code snippet of the failing tests ?

There may be something very granular going on.

I look forward to your response

Best regards

James

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running some basic tests using Espresso on DeviceFarm.

I tried running the Instrumentation tests using a "Custom test environment" as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html).

I believe in my case, the tests didn't get picked up because the "test-filter" wasn't being applied. I modified the spec file to run my tests like this:

```
adb -s $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID shell am instrument -r -w -e class com.your.class.regression.tests --no-window-animation $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_NAME/$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_RUNNER 2>&1 | tee $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/instrument.log
```